# Swift how to send symbols like "&(*(" with HTTP post

Tags: swift

I have got this Swift code

```
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://www.centill.com/ajax/logreg.php")!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "app_log_pass=\(pass_text_field.text!)"
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
```

And when my text is
`(1&*^&&2`
It only prints `(1`.How can i send string that contains various symbols safely with Swift?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Comment: @Alexander adding `addingPercentEncoding` did not help.

Comment: That's very surprising to me. Where did you use it?

Comment: @zneak i understood you not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Sulthan suggested, no predefined `CharacterSet` can be used for actual servers when you want to include some symbol characters in your POST data.

An example `CharacterSet` which I often use:

```
extension CharacterSet {
    static let rfc3986Unreserved = CharacterSet(charactersIn:
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-._~")
}

let postValue = "(1&*^&&2"
let postString = "app_log_pass=\(postValue.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .rfc3986Unreserved)!)"
print(postString) //->app_log_pass=%281%26%2A%5E%26%262
```

Another `CharacterSet` which would work for usual PHP servers:

```
extension CharacterSet {
    static let queryValueAllowed = CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed.subtracting(CharacterSet(charactersIn: "&+="))
}

let postValue = "(1&*^&&2"
let postString = "app_log_pass=\(postValue.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .queryValueAllowed)!)"
print(postString) //->app_log_pass=(1%26*%5E%26%262
```

Anyway, you need to escape the key and the value separately, to prevent escaping the separator `=`.

---

**ADDITION**

An example of escaping multiple key-value pairs:

```
extension String {
    var queryValueEscaped: String {
        return self.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .queryValueAllowed)!
    }
}

let params: [String: String] = [
    "app_log_usn": "OOPer",//usn_text_field.text!,
    "app_log_pass": "(1&*^&&2"//pass_text‌​_field.text!
]
let postString = params.map {"\($0.key)=\($0.value.queryValueEscaped)"}.joined(separator: "&")
print(postString) //->app_log_usn=OOPer&app_log_pass=(1%26*%5E%26%262
```

Assuming each key is made of safe characters and no need to escape.

Comment: But if i have two post values like this `app_log_usn=\(usn_text_field.text!)&app_log_pass=\(pass_text_field.text!)` then it will also escape `&` won't it?

Comment: @sakoaskoaso, as in my answer _you need to escape the key and the value separately_. Something like: `app_log_usn=\(usn_text_field.text!.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .queryValueAllowed)!)&app_log_pass=\(pass_text‌​_field.text!.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .queryValueAllowed)!)`. (It's too long and you'd better split into multiple statements, or define your own extension.)

Comment: By the way, you can use `URLComponents` to build your URLs, too. The only problem it has it not encoding `+` chars.

Comment: @Sulthan, `+` is not included in the OP's example, but password fields of many apps accept `+`. It can be a severe fault for usual servers.

Comment: Thanks for thy help!

Answer (score -1):

Use the [addingPercentEncoding](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/1690785-addingpercentencoding) method with the [urlHostsAllowed](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/characterset/1780202-urlhostallowed) parameter:

`string.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)`

Comment: `postString = postString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)!` didn't work.

Comment: what is postString after you convert it ? What do you mean it didn't work?

Comment: `(1&*%5E&&2` but when i print the result of HTTP request it still returns `(1`

Comment: what is the value of postString after you convert it ?

Comment: it is `(1&*%5E&&2`

Comment: interesting, can you try with this instead: .urlQueryAllowed ?

Comment: This is not how you do URL encoding. You cannot encode the ones that are allowed in `host`. For example, see the [Alamofire implementation](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/5bd458ca09a57fb2999772745d6438585f5140a7/Source/ParameterEncoding.swift#L199). In short, you have to build your own character set starting with `urlQueryAllowed` and then removing the ones that are used as delimiters.